# Downloading pdf files from a website and changing the filename after download

Tags: php

I am trying to download some files. I have written a php script that can gather all of the address of the pdf files I need to download into a array but the file names on that server are odd. How does one go about downloading pdf files with php?

Comment: I tried the file_put_contents, but Im having no success with it. I know my server is se

Comment: se? security enhanced? try to create as subdir if on shared host and download to that.

Comment: I got it, I made a dumb mistake. Works great now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can try (if I understand your question correctly)

```
file_put_contents('/your/file/name.pdf', 
    file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/oddFile.pdf'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out the `file` or `file_get_contents` functions. It can take URLs as well as local filenames.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file.php

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php